# Performance decrease when adding KineticJS nodes to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm working on a floorplan editor program which is implemented in part using HTML5 Canvas and KineticJS. The user can select from a couple of tools to place nodes on the canvas (rooms, hallways, staircases, etc), and can then create edges between the nodes to link them.

I'm running into a problem when placing a specific type of node on my canvas: I can add any number of most types of nodes I've got defined without any performance decrease, but as soon as I try and add more than a handful of 'room' nodes, they take longer and longer to render and the stage tap event handler which creates nodes becomes unresponsive. This issue only occurs on the iPad and not when I run the application from a desktop.

All nodes are comprised of a Kinetic Circle with a particular image to represent the type of node and some data such as x/y position, type, id, and a list of attached edges. The only difference between room nodes and other special nodes is an extra Kinetic Rect and a couple of variables to represent the room itself. When creating a new node, all the attributes are filled by the constructor function, then the node is passed to a setup function to register event handlers and a render function to render it based on its type.

I'm still fairly new with these technologies, so any advice, no matter how specific or general, will probably be helpful. I've attached what I think will be helpful snippets of code; if you need to see more or have questions about what's here please let me know.

Thank you so much for any time and effort.

=========================================================================
EDIT:
Removing the opacity attribute of the room nodes made a huge difference; the performance decrease is almost entirely negligible now. I'll post further updates if and when I work out why that's the case.

```
function Node(x, y, id, type, attr) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.nX = 0;
    this.nY = 0;
    this.type = type;
    this.bbox;
    this.id = id;
    this.edges = {};
    this.attr  = {"zPos": 0,
                  "name": '',
                  "width": default_room_width,
                  "height": default_room_height};

    this.render(x, y, node_radius);
}

Node.prototype.render = function(x, y, r){

    //Create node on canvas
    this.visual = null;
    var _self = this;

    if(this.type == "node" || this.type == "Hallway"){
        this.visual = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            radius: r,
            fill: '#2B64FF',
            stroke: '#000000',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            draggable: true
        });

        nodeLayer.add(this.visual);
        this.x = this.visual.x();
        this.y = this.visual.y();

        nodeLayer.draw();

        this.visual.id = this.id;
        this.setupNode(x, y, node_radius);
    } else {
        var image = new Image();

        _self.visual = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: x - (node_img_size / 2),
            y: y - (node_img_size / 2),
            image: image,
            width: node_img_size,
            height: node_img_size,
            draggable: true
        });
        image.onload = function(){
            _self.setupNode(x, y, node_radius);

            nodeLayer.add(_self.visual);

            _self.x = _self.visual.x();
            _self.y = _self.visual.y();

            nodeLayer.draw();
            _self.visual.id = _self.id;
        }

        image.src = '../../img/' + this.type + 'tool.png';

        var width = this.attr["width"];
        var height = this.attr["height"];

        if(this.type== "room") {
                this.bbox = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                stroke: "black",
                fill: "black",
                opacity: 0.5,
                listening: true,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                offset: {x:width/2, y:height/2}
            });

            setupRoom(this.bbox);

            this.bbox.offsetX(default_room_width/2);
            this.bbox.offsetY(default_room_height/2);

            roomLayer.add(this.bbox);
            roomLayer.draw();
        }
    }
}

//Bind event handlers for rooms
function setupRoom(room) {
    room.on(tap, function(e) {
        if(selectedRoom == this) {
            selectedRoom = null;
            this.setOpacity(0.5);
            roomLayer.draw();
        } else {
            if(selectedRoom != null)
                selectedRoom.setOpacity(0.5);

            selectedRoom = this;
            this.setOpacity(1);
            roomLayer.draw();
        }
    });

    room.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
        is_hovering = true;
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e) {
        is_hovering = false;
    });
}

Node.prototype.setupNode = function (x, y) {

    var _self = this;
    var c = this.visual;

    c.on('mouseenter', function(e){
        is_hovering = true;
    }).on('mouseleave', function(e){
        is_hovering = false;
    });

    c.on(tap, function(e){
        if(is_adding_node == true && _self.type == "node" && linkerNode != _self) {
            is_adding_node = false;
            nodeDrag = false;

            $.each(nodes, function(key, value) {
                if(value.type == "node") {
                    value.visual.fill("#2B64FF");
                }
            });
            nodeLayer.batchDraw();
            joinNodes(linkerNode, _self);

        } else {
            handleNodeTap(e, _self);
        }
    });

    c.on(dbltap, function(e){
        console.log(_self.id);
        if(selectedTool != "link"){
            showMenuForNode(c);
        }
    });

    //Drag event
    c.on(touchstart, function(e){
        nodeDrag = true;
    }).on(touchmove, function(e){
        var touchPos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        var newX = c.x() + offsetX * -1;
        var newY = c.y() + offsetY * -1;

        _self.x = newX;
        _self.y = newY;

        if(_self.text != null) {
            _self.text.x(_self.visual.x() - node_text_offset);
            _self.text.y(_self.visual.y() - node_text_offset);
        }

        //Move room BB if set
        if (_self.bbox != undefined) {
            _self.bbox.x(_self.visual.x() + _self.visual.width()/2);
            _self.bbox.y(_self.visual.y() + _self.visual.height()/2);
            roomLayer.batchDraw();
        }

        //Update positions of connected edges
        for(var x in _self.edges){
            edges[_self.edges[x]].setPosition();
        }

        nodeLayer.batchDraw();

    }).on(touchend, function(e){
        currentNode = _self;
        nodeDrag = false;
    });
};
```

Comment: Try avoiding opacity changes. Instead set the room-rect fill to full-black (#000) or half-black (#808080 or similar);

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks! Do you think that could cause such a slowdown, or is it just a good practice?

Comment: @markE That fixed the problem I was running into, thank you. Do you know any reason why even setting a static opacity gives iPad such a rough time?

Comment: ...Glad to help. Opacity is a blending operation while drawing a solid rectangle is a replacing operation.  Blending requires multiple reads and calculations per pixel===slower. Replacing is simply setting a pixel color===faster.